# One Object Looks Like Material / Texture is Noisy

Tags: texturing, materials, objects

I have rendered a 2 min animation that I'm pretty happy with (my first go with Blender) using models I created. The render was great, noticed a few mistakes so I was going to do some more editing.

I now notice one of the objects has become very noisy, screenshot below. I can't get the texture back. Everything looks fine within Material & Texture in the Properties section of the object. I've even tried to relink the material and UV maps from the object beside it in the screenshot as they are essentially the same object.

Have I just accidentally added noise to the object somehow? To new to Blender to figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Double check that you don't have a duplicate of the geometry there - it looks like Z fighting that happens when there is duplicates sitting in the same place.

Comment: Ah yes indeed Craig, that was the problem. You can even see the culprit in the original screenshot - Element2.001, many thanks!